# Second email from Journey does not have personalization content

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Following the Journey Builder for Apps book (http://code.exacttarget.com/resources/jb4a-dev-ebook.pdf), I have everything working except the second email in the Journey (the coupon email) does not include the personalization content. This content is in the data extension that initiates the trigger not the All Subscribers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now personalization attributes are pulled from profile attributes (All subscribers list).
if you need personalization from data extensions, you would need to use ampscript to reference that.

I believe with the next release, there is 'Data binding' which would pull in personalization directly from the contact model (aka data extension)

Comment: I just found this: http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/canvas_activities/#ConfiguringAnActivity. There is a note that says "Journey Builder does not support personalization from a Data Extension field.  Emails using AMPScript can use the Data Extension Lookup() function to interact with data extensions in your ExactTarget account.".  Thanks Arvind.

Comment: Note that support for personalization strings in email was introduced to Journey Builder in the [Nov 2014 release](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/resources/release_notes/november_2014_release/).